# Method to "unzip" and "zip" this boot image with root filesystem folders?

Tags: initramfs, root-filesystem

I am struggling with "unzipping" and "zipping" back this root filesystem from my bootable usb.
I have found some similar questions but they are too old, i think, and maybe the root file packing has changed a little bit over the time (im not linux expert, i just like digging in to learn something new).

The root file inspection looks like this.:

```
homelab@homelab-DH310V2:~/Desktop/stock/bzroot_folder$ binwalk bzroot_orig

DECIMAL       HEXADECIMAL     DESCRIPTION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0             0x0             ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC), file name: "."
112           0x70            ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC), file name: "kernel"
232           0xE8            ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC), file name: "kernel/x86"
356           0x164           ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC), file name: "kernel/x86/microcode",
488           0x1E8           ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC), file name: "kernel/x86/microcode/GenuineIntel.bin"
3624572       0x374E7C        ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC), file name: "kernel/x86/microcode/AuthenticAMD.bin"
3655268       0x37C664        ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC), file name: "TRAILER!!!"
3655680       0x37C800        xz compressed data
14747435      0xE1072B        EBML file
27330002      0x1A105D2       mcrypt 2.5 encrypted data, algorithm: "-", keysize: 14961 bytes, mode: "V",
43539972      0x2985E04       Unix path: /usr/local/go/src/runtime/runtime-gdb.py
58338583      0x37A2D17       Zlib compressed data, default compression
79135327      0x4B7825F       PARity archive data - file number 5362
93608855      0x5945B97       ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC)
125494792     0x77AE608       MPEG transport stream data
139663506     0x8531892       Zlib compressed data, default compression
139663558     0x85318C6       Zlib compressed data, default compression
139663590     0x85318E6       Zlib compressed data, default compression
139664346     0x8531BDA       Zlib compressed data, default compression
139666162     0x85322F2       Zlib compressed data, default compression
139666194     0x8532312       Zlib compressed data, default compression
139666774     0x8532556       Zlib compressed data, default compression
139670750     0x85334DE       ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC)
140843025     0x8651811       gzip compressed data, last modified: 2082-09-03 16:48:36 (bogus date)
```

I can see there is early microcode + a lot of other stuff.
From other questions and answers i was expecting only the kernel microcode files and the "zip" file, but there is a lot more going on.

I am able to split the Kernel and other things to 2 files (Kernel + others), i got even somehow unpacked the root filesystem, but there is no way to pack it back the same way, and of course it will not boot correctly if i do it.

I am not looking specifically for the exact answer, but someone may lead me in the right path.